When writing 'import languagemodels as lm', receiving the following error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'languagemodels'
Please help me installing related proper Module to avoid receiving this error.
I have installed the module 'languagemodels 0.18.0', and still receiving the error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'languagemodels'

Welcome, please share your full code and error.

Does anything come up when you run the command pip show languagemodels? Do you have more than one Python version installed?

yes when running pip show languagemodels, receiving: Name: languagemodels
Version: 0.18.0
Summary: Simple inference for large language models
Home-page: https://github.com/jncraton/languagemodels
Author: Jon Craton
Author-email: jon@joncraton.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: C:\Users\s.najjar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages
Requires: ctranslate2, huggingface-hub, tokenizers

Yes two versions of Python are installed .

Python 3.8.5 and python 3.12.2 versions.

Please don't add comments to clarify; [edit] your question instead.
